# Using shared memory between user and kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to share memory between user and kernel space in linux. 
This memory space should be accessible from user.

I am thinking to use mmap() on user program and get kernel to allocate memory, especially physical address which later be fed into mmap() using /dev/mem.

What is function call in kernel driver to "get kernel to allocate memory and return the reserved physical address?"

Thanks

Comment: You need [aligned pages](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch11lev1sec3) so that you can map them, right?

Comment: Yes. I believe so.